# AC motor turning a certain turns and stop, then can turns reverse only for certain turns

Tags: motor, ac

I bought this motor from some one who said it was used in an automatic recliner armchair sofa.

The motor can turn only certain turns [set N] and stop, then can turns reverse only. It can resume the same direction turning if manually stop it before it reached N, till got N and stop.

Any suggestions?

[image]

---

OK, here comes the result feedback. I opened the motor and found that there is a sets of gear group in the back end, which drives a drum wheel that can trig a limit switch after certain turns.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You managed to make your whole post into a hyperlink. I have fixed that but I haven't fixed your question which is not understandable. You have not explained what you want the motor to do. If English is not your first language then please state this in your user profile text or location and we will try to help. Try to find the datasheet for the motor and add a link into your question.

Comment: Yes, I want the motor running continuous？

Comment: OK. So edit your question to explain that and add the link and update your user profile.

Comment: Is there some type of limit switch assembly under the cover? If there is then you will have to disable it.

Comment: Didn't see any switch, the capacitance case is quite big, may some thing built in? I'll open and check it.

Comment: Hi Michel, can you tell how to edit that? sorry a newbie.

Comment: @loadam, There is an edit link under your question.

Comment: For future reference, it is a good idea to rotate images so they can be read and crop them before posting. Also try for the best focus.

Answer (score 3):

This is what is known as a "gearhead motor" — a motor married directly to a gearbox.

The motion limits are built into the gearbox, so you'll have to remove or modify that in order to get continuous motion. That's a mechanical question, not an electrical one.

**However**, note that the motor itself is labeled "DUTY INT.", which means that it's only rated for intermittent duty cycle operation. It may overheat when run continuously.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave, I'll open and do it later.

Comment: OK, here comes the result feedback. I opened the motor and found that there is a sets of gear group in the back end, which drives a  drum wheel that can trig a limit switch after certain turns. Thank you again Dave, I'll attache the picture later.